# sql server - joining value from embedded not in query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query -

```
select a.applicationName 'Application Name', ug.shortName 'ITAM Owner', d.dbName 'Database Name', s.serverName 'Database Server Name' from tblApplications a
inner join tblUserGroups ug on ug.groupId = a.recordOwnerId
inner join tblApplicationDatabaseLinks adl on adl.applicationId = a.applicationId
inner join tblDatabases d on d.dbId = adl.dbId
inner join tblServers s on s.serverId = d.serverId
where a.applicationName = 'AppABC' and s.serverId not in (
select s.serverId from tblApplications a
inner join tblApplicationServerLinks asl on asl.applicationId = a.applicationId
inner join tblServers s on s.serverId = asl.serverId
where a.applicationName = 'AppABC')
```

It works fine on a one to one basis but I want to run it globally.

How do I effectively `join` the `a.applicationName` from the parent query to the `a.applicationName` from the subquery?

I want it to look something like this:

```
select a.applicationName 'Application Name', ug.shortName 'ITAM Owner', d.dbName 'Database Name', s.serverName 'Database Server Name' from tblApplications a
inner join tblUserGroups ug on ug.groupId = a.recordOwnerId
inner join tblApplicationDatabaseLinks adl on adl.applicationId = a.applicationId
inner join tblDatabases d on d.dbId = adl.dbId
inner join tblServers s on s.serverId = d.serverId
where s.serverId not in (
select s.serverId from tblApplications a
inner join tblApplicationServerLinks asl on asl.applicationId = a.applicationId
inner join tblServers s on s.serverId = asl.serverId)
```

Which doesn't work because it's not knowing that the `a.applicationId` should match eachother.

Comment: Alias tableApplications differently.  A in outer can't be refered if you have an A on the inner, then you can coorlate the queries.

Comment: You can use a join or exists instead of the in clause.  http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx

Comment: @JoeC - please post this as an answer as it works I read the page and got the correct solution from it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't give the Applications table the same alias in both the subquery and the outer query.  Instead of `a`, call one of them  `a1` or something like that.

Then you can correlate the subquery to the outer query with the two different aliases.

Comment: can you explain this?  I've tried aliasing them to `ao` and `ai` to no success (`applications inner` and `applications outer`)

Comment: After you changed the aliases, did you also add `ao.applicationId=ai.applicationId` in the subquery ?   That's how you correlate the subquery and force the applicationIds to match.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was provided from the comments by @JoeC but for anyone else here is what I had to do:

```
select ao.applicationName 'Application Name', ug.shortName 'ITAM Owner', d.dbName 'Database Name', s.serverName 'Database Server Name' from tblApplications ao
inner join tblUserGroups ug on ug.groupId = ao.recordOwnerId
inner join tblApplicationDatabaseLinks adl on adl.applicationId = ao.applicationId
inner join tblDatabases d on d.dbId = adl.dbId
inner join tblServers s on s.serverId = d.serverId
where s.serverId not in (
select s.serverId from tblApplications ai
inner join tblApplicationServerLinks asl on asl.applicationId = ai.applicationId
inner join tblServers s on s.serverId = asl.serverId
where ai.applicationId = ao.applicationId)
order by ao.applicationName asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a join or exists instead of the in clause. weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/05/18/60210.aspx